# g:remoteLink events not being called with grails 2.3

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

The code below shows an example of g:remoteLink which is
called from within a grails gsp.

The action is called successfully.
When run using grails 1.3.7, the events are called.
When run using grails 2.3.8, the events are not called.

How can the g:remoteLink call be run successfully under 2.3?

```
<html>
<head>
<g:javascript library="prototype" />
</head>
<body>
<g:remoteLink action="f__" 
    onSuccess="alert('found');"
    on404="alert('not found');"
    on405="document.location='${application.contextPath}/user/ferr';">
    Update
</g:remoteLink>    
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you,
S

Comment: Which events aren't being called? Also, be aware that all the remoteX tags are going away in future versions of Grails.

Comment: Hello Joshua,None of the events listed are being called. Am particularly interested in the on404 event since I am upgrading from the earlier version of grails which contains the on404 event handler.

Comment: Is there a way I can obtain an answer to this? It is pretty urgent. Thanks Steve